# Issue Related to ItemClick Event in ASPXMenu in Devexpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have ASPXMenu and Bind Items from the database.. I have added ItemClickEvent..

it does fire on Parant Menu

but when i click on Items under the Parant Item.. it doesn't fire.

how can fire it?

```
 protected void mMain_ItemClick(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu.MenuItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";
    }
```

Comment: This code is irrelevant, you should post code/markup where you define ASPxMenu.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to handle the server-side [ItemClick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxMenuASPxMenuBase_ItemClicktopic) event as described in our documentation.
If you want to process it, you have to remove the NavigateUrl property definition from a menu item, and then perform the response redirection via the Response.Redirect method.

```
protected void ASPxMenu1_ItemClick(object source, DevExpress.Web.ASPxMenu.MenuItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "The clicked item: " + e.Item.Text;
    }
```